# How to erase/wipe all ext4 metadata, not just the filesystem signature 53 ef?

Tags: ext4, delete, superblock

I want to make zero all bits of a partition where an ext4 filesystem structure existed (superblocks, metadata, journal, etc), not just the filesystem signature deleted by `wipefs`.

I can quickly zero out files content using `shred` utility, but not the metadata.
On block devices supporting `TRIM/DISCARD`, this is easy as I can quickly run `blkdiscard` on the entire partition.

However on large rotational HDDs where `TRIM/DISCARD` is not available, making all bits zero either becomes a large time consuming process or implies destroying/regenerating the disk encryption key (on self encrypting drives) which implies losing entire drive, not just the ext4 partition.

Other than reading `mke2fs` code and creating an imaginary `wipe2fs` tool based on it, is there already another way to quickly wipe all ext4 superblocks/metadata?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such utilities but given a programming background you could hack `e2image` to do exactly what you're looking for as this utility by default saves only metadata.

Comment: What about using dd you can “dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/path bs=4096” does this meet your needs

Comment: @JasonCroyle he said he doesn't want to zero the whole drive because that takes too long.  Though I do wonder if you actually care about not leaving behind anything someone might find later, why are you trying to take a shortcut?  Zero the whole thing or there is probably something somewhere that you don't want left behind.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this several years ago as part of a scripted remote install to remove all the superblocks so that a subsequent mkfs wouldn't ask "do you really want to do this..." question in the middle of an unattended install. Testing was limited to a single device with 2 partitions.

```
# Overwrite any existing superblocks for the filesystem on each partition
#
# Zero out the superblock where the filesystems will be. If we don't do this,
# when we reimage a disk mkfs will see the superblocks of the filesystem which
# may have previously been here and and ask for a y/n confirmation before
# proceeding which requires more manual intervention (see disk geometry below)
# This gets a little complicated since the mkfs scatters superblocks across the
# partition to protect against failure so you just can't just zero out the
# beginning of the partition.
# Note that fdisk reports in units of 512 byte blocks (-u) ($FD_BS) but
# the file system may have different blocksize ($FS_BS). When we dd seek to zero
# out the superblock, we need to seek X file system blocks (in FS_BS) from
# the beginning of the partition (in FD_BS) so we use the FS_MULT to help make
# the math more obvious.

overwriteAnySuperblocks() {

fdisk -u -l ${TGTDEV} | grep -v EFI |
        sed -n '/^\//{ s/\*/ /; p}' | # only line that start with /, delete '*'
    while read PART FIRST_BLOCK IGNORE_REST_OF_LINE
    do
        FD_BS=512   # fdisk reports in 512 byte blocks
        echo "Partition $PART starts at $FIRST_BLOCK fdisk blocks" >&2
        # get the file system block size - may be a 4k file system
        FS_BS=$(dumpe2fs "${PART}" 2>/dev/null |
                sed -n '/^Block size/s/^Block size: *\([0-9]*$\)/\1/p')
        echo "File system block size from dumpe2fs - FS_BS=$FS_BS" >&2
        [[ -z "${FS_BS}" ]] && continue # no filesystem on this partition
        # file system block as a multiple of 512 byte blocks
        FS_MULT=$(( FS_BS / FD_BS ))
        echo "File system block size $FS_BS is $FS_MULT x $FD_BS fdisk blocks" >&2
        # zero out the beginning of each partition
        # zero out backup superblocks
        dumpe2fs "${PART}" 2>/dev/null |
            sed -n '/superblock/s/^.*block at \([0-9]*\).*/\1/p' |
            while read SUPERBLOCK
            do
                echo "Zeroing superblock at FS $SUPERBLOCK" >&2
                #echo dd if=/dev/zero of=${TGTDEV} bs=${FD_BS} \
                #    seek=$((${FIRST_BLOCK}+(${SUPERBLOCK}*${FS_MULT}))) \
                #    count=2048
                dd if=/dev/zero of=${TGTDEV} bs=${FD_BS} \
                    seek=$(( FIRST_BLOCK + (SUPERBLOCK*FS_MULT) )) \
                    count=2048
            done
    done
```

}

Comment: I've been running into problems with ghosts of departed filesystems; after re-partitioning an emmc, e2fsck sees a valid filesystem when it is actually subtly corrupt. Thanks for showing how hard this is to do right; I'm just going to blast the whole partition with dd.

Answer (score -1):

We used to simply dd zeros across the first blocks of the partition

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=512 count=512 of=/dev/your_partition
```

Comment: This doesn't erase all the metadata, as required by the question